# How to select data from a partition table using php , postgreSQL

Tags: php, postgresql, partitioning

I have an issue on knowing how partition tables works exactly .

So , i have a table that is containing about 10000000 records .

To get my data from php page im running this code :

```php
<select id="computation_date" name="computation_date" class="form-control input-lg" data-live-search="true">

<option value="">Select Computation Date</option>
<?php

// Select last computation date
$query_last_date = "SELECT datecalcul from Table_Name ORDER BY datecalcul DESC LIMIT 1";
$result_last_date = pg_query($query_last_date);
$row_last_date = pg_fetch_assoc($result_last_date);

// Fetch all the Computation Date data 
$query_date = "SELECT DISTINCT datecalcul as d_datecalcul from Table_Name ORDER BY datecalcul ASC";
$result_date = pg_query($query_date);
while ($row_date = pg_fetch_assoc($result_date)) {
echo '<option value="' . $row_date['datecalcul'] . '">' . $row_date['datecalcul'] . '</option>';
                    }
echo '<option value="' . $row_last_date['datecalcul'] . '"  selected="selected">' . $row_last_date['datecalcul'] . '</option>';
$last_date = $row_last_date['datecalcul'];
?>

</select>
```

So ,  i figured  out that to handle lots of Data i have to use **partition Tables** to optimize and increase performance in displaying data in php web page

So i have , partitioned my 'Table_Name ' using this code on PostgreSQL :

```SQL
-- step 1 - declare table defintion
create table Table_Truncate (
LIKE Table_Name INCLUDING ALL)
PARTITION BY RANGE (datecalcul);


-- step 2 - declare partitions
create table Table_Truncate_2021 PARTITION OF Table_Truncate
for values from ('2021-01-01') TO ('2021-12-31');

create table Table_Truncate_2020 PARTITION OF Table_Truncate
for values from ('2020-01-01') TO ('2020-12-31');

create table Table_Truncate_2023 PARTITION OF Table_Truncate
for values from ('2023-01-01') TO ('2023-12-31');

create table Table_Truncate_2022 PARTITION OF Table_Truncate
for values from ('2022-01-01') TO ('2022-12-31');

create table Table_Truncate_2000 PARTITION OF Table_Truncate
for values from ('2000-01-01') TO ('2000-12-31');

-- step 3 insert data
insert into Table_Truncate
select * from Table_Name ;
```

My question is , ***how can i display my data into php page using partition Tables ?*** or doesthe fact that i have partitionned my table i don't modify my php code ?

Comment: Table is a reserved word in SQL, that will never work as a table name. And no, using double quotes " won't make it better, it's just a delay in the problems you're going to face. Use a better name.

Comment: I wrote table just to illustrate my example ! otherwise it's named other in my code

Comment: When you select data from the parent table, the database server will get it from the partitions when needed. You don't have to do anything in your application code.

Comment: So , i will have just to call the partitionned   main  table

Comment: For your application it is completely irrelevant if a table is partitioned or not. Just select the data that you need, construct your where conditions, join conditions or whatever, just like you always did. Your application doesn't care, it's only the database that cares about the technical implementation.

Answer (score 0):

> So , i figured out that to handle lots of Data i have to use partition Tables to optimize and increase performance in displaying data in php web page

No, in your case you query all the rows of the table.

> how can i display my data into php page using partition Tables

By accessibg the partition(s) you need, that's no sense in your case.

Analysing your code I imagine that you have a limited list of "date_calcul" (if not your select will not work) and this "date_calcul" are historical data.

If this is right I should keep the old records of your calculation in a table "calculation_dates" that you should update after each calculation and query this small table that will drastically improve what you call "display performance" but that's in fact server cpu time.